# PTRACE_SINGLESTEP not moving %rip

Tags: c, ptrace

So I'm writing a debugger. In the debugger, I want persistent breakpoints. Right now I'm just working on getting it set up for one breakpoint only. When I tell the debugger to continue, I do this...

```
ptrace( PTRACE_GETREGS, child, NULL, &regs);
printf("%lx\n", regs.rip);
ptrace( PTRACE_SINGLESTEP, child, NULL, NULL);
ptrace( PTRACE_GETREGS, child, NULL, &regs);
printf("%lx\n", regs.rip);
ptrace( PTRACE_POKETEXT, child, (void *)original_addr, (original_data & ~0xff) | 0xcc);
```

However, I get the output...

```
40053d
40053d
```

Meaning the rip has not actually updated. This is consistent with the fact that when I continue more times than it iterates over the breakpoint, it still is in the breakpoint. Any thoughts?

EDIT:
So here's the problem. The child does not actually run the SINGLESTEP until it sees a wait() call, at which point it runs and returns control to the parent when it does a single instruction. I didn't call wait, so it didn't update at that point. So it simply printed out the same one twice. Then, it reached the checkpoint status, and updated to the original %rip, at the start of the instruction. Cheers.

Comment: how do you set a breakpoint?

Comment: @GiuseppePes store the address of the breakpoint into original_addr (global), and then original_data (global) = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKTEXT, child, (void*)original_addr, NULL); and ptrace(PTRACE_POKETEXT, child, (void*)original_addr, (original data & ~0xff) | 0xcc);

Comment: After the break point is hit, are you putting back the original instruction?

Comment: Yes I'm doing something like this...

`if (WTIFSTOPPED( status )) {
   if (original_addr != 0) {
      ptrace( PTRACE_GETREGS, child, NULL, &regs);
      regs.rid = original_addr;
      ptrace( PTRACE_SETREGS, child, NULL, &regs);
      ptrace( PTRACE_POKETEXT, child, (void*)original_addr, original_data);
   }
 }`

Comment: why `rid`? and not `rip`?

Comment: That was a typo, I figured it out. I'm updating the question.

Comment: @GiuseppePes Did any of you find what was wrong? I'm facing same issue

Comment: Never mind, found the bug.. The data returned by ptrace on PEEKTEXT is 64bits long and I was assigning the result to int32_t which lost the instruction data, so when I removed the breakpoint by restoring the original instruction data it corrupted the instruction stream which produced a SEGFAULT on single stepping, thus RIP didn't change as tracer stopped because of Segfault and not because of SIGTRAP/breakpoint